# Attempting to write a for loop in java, but cannot figure out correct logic

Tags: java, for-loop

I am still learning the basics of Java and I'm having trouble using for loop logic properly.  I'm currently creating a program that prints verses of the "Beer Bottle" song.  My code runs properly and is complete, however my logic is flawed.  I've been messing around with this for loop for a couple of days now and I'm still not sure what it should look like.

The objective of the program is to prompt the user for how many verses of the "Beer Bottle" song they want printed.  If the user enters 2, then the following should appear:

```
100 bottles of beer on the wall

100 bottles of beer

If one of those bottles should happen to fall

99 bottles of beer on the wall

99 bottles of beer on the wall

99 bottles of beer

If one of those bottles should happen to fall

98 bottles of beer on the wall
```

My code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BottleSong 
{

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    printBottleSongVerses ();
}

public static void printBottleSongVerses () 
{   
    int versesToPrint;
    int verseNumber;
    int state;
    state = 0;
    versesToPrint = 0;
    verseNumber = 0;

    String checkInt;
    checkInt = null;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println ("This program prints verses of the 'One Hundred Bottles of Beer' song.");
    System.out.println ("How many verses would you like to read?");

    if (scan.hasNextInt()) 
    {   
    versesToPrint = scan.nextInt();
    state = 1;
    }
    else System.out.println("Error! This program only accepts integer values!");
    if (state == 1)
    {   

    if (versesToPrint <= 100)
    {   

        for (; versesToPrint > 0 ; versesToPrint--)
        {
            verseNumber = 101 - versesToPrint;
        System.out.println (verseNumber + " bottles of beer on the wall");
        System.out.println (verseNumber + " bottles of beer");
        System.out.println ("If one of those bottles should happen to fall"); 
        System.out.println (verseNumber - 1  + " bottles of beer on the wall");
        }
    }
    }

}   
}
```

Now I know there is some unnecessary code in there, but that's because I've been playing around with it for a while.  It works, but it prints the verses in reverse.  If 3 is the input, then the console prints 98, then 99 then 100.  I need it to print the other way.  Can anyone help with fixing my logic?

Comment: You might try just a small change; uses verses to print to count the number of verses, like you have it. Then do "verseNumber = 101" outside our loop (before the for loop), and change the line that says verseNumber = 101... to "verseNumber--". Thus the for loop counts the number of verses to run through, while the verse number drops by one each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the approach slightly and just write the loop around the number of verses and change the number of bottles on the wall.

```
int numberOfBottles = 100;
if (versesToPrint <= 100)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < versesToPrint; i++)
    {
    System.out.println (numberOfBottles + " bottles of beer on the wall");
    System.out.println (numberOfBottles + " bottles of beer");
    System.out.println ("If one of those bottles should happen to fall"); 
    System.out.println (numberOfBottles - 1  + " bottles of beer on the wall");
    numberOfBottles--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This is how I decided to go about fixing my issue and it works great.

Comment: @user3342055 no problem. Be sure to accept it as the answer if you found it helpful. Accepting answers is as important as asking questions here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop variable:

```
for (int verseNumber = 100; verseNumber > 100 - versesToPrint; verseNumber--)
```